# ios - shoud UIAlertView be used in the returning block of NSUrlConnection?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsurlconnection, uialertview

I get some rare crashing happening when I use a UIAlertView in the return block of NSUrlConnection.  Am I not allowed to use the UIAlertView in the asynchronous thread like that?

Most of the time, it seems to work fine.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks I was trying to make an alert message to the user. What is an alternative I could use instead of the UIAlertView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All UI related code is need to be work on main thread.

I got a similar crash when I displayed the alertView on another thread.

You need to display the alertView using either `dispatch_async` or `performSelectorOnMainThread`.

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                    message:@"Message" 
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

          [alert show];
       });
```

**or**

```
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" 
                    message:@"Message" 
                delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntillDone:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only use UIAlertView on main thread.
Use `performSelectorOnMainThread:<#(SEL)#> withObject:<#(id)#> waitUntilDone:<#(BOOL)#>` in your return block.